# middleware not executing after successful login

Tags: laravel-5

AdminMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request);

    if (\Auth::user() && \Auth::user()->isAdmin() == 1) {
            return view('adminpage');
        } else {
            return view('homepage');
        }
    }
}
```

User.php:

```
public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->is_admin;
}
```

UserController.php:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    if(\Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password])) {
        // i dont know what if successfull login, i need to execute the logic written in AdminMiddleware
    } else {
        return view('login);
    }
}
```

My table contains a boolean field "is_admin" with `1` for `xxx@gmail.com`

Comment: you dont need to execute the middleware, you just need to redirect them where you want ... you could just redirect them to any route that has that middleware on it, and that would cause that middleware to direct them where you want on the next request .... but putting `return ...` as the first line in your middleware is skipping everything else in that middleware.

Comment: but after making request to controller only it will authenticate i hope.